# MySQL - Fastest way to select relational data avoiding left join

Tags: mysql, performance, select, join

I've currently got a query that selects metrics data from two tables whilst getting the projects to query from two other tables (one is owned projects, the other is projects to which the user has access).

```
SELECT v.`projectID`,
(SELECT COUNT(m.`session`) 
    FROM `metricData` m
    WHERE m.`projectID` = v.`projectID`) AS `sessions`,
(SELECT COUNT(pb.`interact`)
    FROM `interactionData` pb WHERE pb.`projectID` = v.`projectID` GROUP BY pb.`projectID`) AS `interactions`
FROM `medias` v
LEFT JOIN `projectsExt` pa ON v.`projectsExtID` = pa.`projectsExtID`
WHERE (pa.`user` = '1' OR v.`ownerUser` = '1')
GROUP BY v.`projectID`
```

It takes too long, 1-2seconds. This is obviously the multi left-join scenario. But, I've got a couple of ideas to improve speed and wondered what the thoughts were in principle. Do I:-

- Try and select the list in the query and then get the data, rather than doing the joins. Not sure how this would work.
- Do a select in a separate query to get the projectIDs and then run queries on each projectID afterwards. This may lead to hundreds of potentially thousands of requests, but may be better for the processing?
- Other ideas?

Comment: Try 'em! Also, try index(es), and see what you get from an explain plan.

Comment: Hmm, kinda looking for a broader advice based on experience here. I've got indexes of course.

Comment: OK, but if you do an explain plan and post the results here, experts on mysql (not me :-) will have a better idea of what needs tweaking.

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful? Please let us know and mark one as answered if so.

Comment: Though broadly helpful, they're not a resolve (nothing has shaved any time off my query). So I can't (as SO constantly tries to get you to do) say it's a solved answer. I am still working on this and will update when I do find a full resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two questions here:

1. how can I get my result in less than 2 seconds
2. how can I avoid a left join.

To answer #1 properly there has to be more information. Technical information, such as the explain plan for this particular query is a good start. Even better if we'd have the SHOW CREATE TABLE of all tables that you access, as well as the number of rows they contain.

But I'd also appreciate more functional information: what exactly is the question you're trying to answer? Right now, it seems you're looking at two different sets of medias:

1. either there is no matching row in projectsExt, in which case medias.ownerUser must equal '1' (is that '1' supposed to be a string btw?)
2. or there is exactly one mathching row in projectsExt for which projectsExt.user must equal '1' (is that '1' supposed to be a string btw?)

By lack of enough information to answer #1, I can answer #2 - "how to avoid a left join". Answer is: write a UNION of the two sets, one where there is a match and one where there isn't a match.

```
SELECT v.`projectID`
,      (
       SELECT COUNT(m.`session`) 
       FROM `metricData` m
       WHERE m.`projectID` = v.`projectID`
       ) AS `sessions`
,      (
       SELECT COUNT(pb.`interact`)
       FROM `interactionData` pb
       WHERE pb.`projectID` = v.`projectID`
       GROUP BY pb.`projectID`
) AS `interactions`
FROM ( 
    SELECT      v.projectID
    FROM medias 
    WHERE ownerUser = '1'
    GROUP BY projectID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      v.projectID
    FROM medias v
    INNER JOIN projectsExt pa
    ON         v.projectsExtID = pa.projectsExtID
    WHERE      v.ownerUser != '1'
    AND        pa.user = '1'
    GROUP BY v.`projectID
) v
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, instead, to refactor everything into left joins? Seeing as how you're always grouping on the same field, it shouldn't be a problem. Try that and post an `EXPLAIN` to see what the bottlenecks are.

Subselects are less performant than joins, because the engine can optimize the joins to a much higher degree. In fact, subselects will usually, where applicable, be rewritten into joins by the engine where possible.

As a rule of a thumb, there is no gain in splitting queries, all you gain is overhead and confusing the optimizer. There are, as always, exceptions to this rule, but they come into play after you've done what you can traditionally and know you keen such an approach.

Comment: Do you mean, write the subselects in the SELECT list also as a LEFT JOIN? The problem with that approach usually is that both metricData and interactionData are likely to have more than 1 row for a given projectId. (Why else would the OP do a COUNT on those tables). If that assumption is true, then the matching sets in metricData and interactionData would form a cartesian product, since they are only related to the main medias set and not related to each other. This is usually very expensive, and it's not trivial to extract the requested COUNTs either in that case.

Comment: You could do this if you'd first LEFT JOIN say metricData, then GROUP BY and calculate its count, per projectId and then do the LEFT JOIN to   interactionData, then GROUP BY on that, to COUNT the interactionData, and SUM the COUNTS of metricData of the inner nested level. But this is pretty painful to rewrite, and since it relies on multitple SELECT's in the FROM clause not exactly efficient either. Worth a shot when other paths have been explored without success.