# Best way to select related items from two separate tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I looked at some [S/O posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027522/mysql-fastest-way-to-select-relational-data-avoiding-left-join) and am not getting it. I think I can do this without needing to use `JOIN`.

I have 2 tables:

```
pagecontents : content, pages_id
pages        : id, title
```

Of course there is a simple relation here, as `pagecontents.pages_id` is always the same as `pages.id`.

I'm submitting a search with the query below:

```
SELECT `pages_id`, 
MATCH(`content`) AGAINST('search term' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
FROM `pagecontents` 
WHERE 
MATCH(`content`) AGAINST ('search term' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

The query returns results as expected, but:

**My problem**
I want to get the `pages.title` for each of the search result set rows. I can't figure out how, and I think it's probably something really easy.

Comment: You need to join the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `pages_id`, pages.title,
MATCH(`content`) AGAINST('search term' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
FROM `pagecontents` JOIN pages ON pagecontents.pages_id = pages.id 
WHERE 
MATCH(`content`) AGAINST ('search term' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY score DESC;
```